# How to find the longest set of consecutive increasing (ascending) elements in array?

Tags: data-structures, mergesort, array-merge

One straightforward way to find it is just check each element and its following element and include it in another array. But it's not so clear. Another way would be Divide & Conquer approach using Merge Sorting algorithm. In this case it's not supposed to sort numbers but divide them recursively in subarrays and merge only those numbers which satisfy condition n < n+1. But I'm not sure about code implementation of program that is merging and checking part.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using a single pass scan operation on the candidate array to see the length of the consecutive increasing sequence. So the pseudocode can be like the following:

```
a = [5 1 3 10 5 15 25 35 45 3 4 5];
longest_seq = 1;
temp_sec = 1;
for i =1:size(a)
    if a[i-1]<a[i[
       temp_sec = temp_sec +1;
    else 
       if(temp_sec  > longest_seq )
           longest_seq  = temp_sec ;
       end
       temp_sec  = 1;
    end
end
```

`longest_seq` is the number you are looking for (To my understanding).

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstand your problem but why use separate arrays, merging, sorting, etc.?  If as I understand it you're just looking for the longest sequence of increasing elements, recursion could be your friend.  Pass a pointer to element N to func(n), if N+1 is greater than N, then N++, and call func(N) calls itself again (making sure you don't exceed the bounds of your array.

A simplistic explanation but think you see what I'm driving at.